# Images permissioning issue in IONIC 3 on OSX

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I know how to use images in the imgs folder of the ionic the problem is something like this

**1:** I was trying to get to know with hotspot feature of OSX and accidentally I changed the name of my computer's local network which caused my **NPM** to crash, means no build were possible for IONIC except using SUDO commands which is not recommended by IONIC guys.

**2:** here what I did!! I uninstalled everything of IONIC ,NODE,NPM and CORDOVA and reinstalled them globally and all things worked just fine and all commands got back in action EXCEPT this new issue!

now that I was using images in img folder before all that mess !

> whenever I run a command either to build or emulate I get unable to
>   access images error CAUSE PERMISSION ISSUES

here are the snapShots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well after a deep search I have found a solution thnx to my teacher Mike Hartington

here it is!!! how to solve the issue

I ran an ionic command with sudo most likely, which had changed the permissions of mine project

to solve I did this!

ran this command

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/<Path/to/project
```

then ran my build or emulate commands ***without*** **sudo** and every thing came to normal
hope this helps!